# PhoneGap + Pass default parameter with every HTTP request with out adding to every URL

Tags: angularjs, cordova, http, phonegap-plugins

In my PhoneGap app, I am trying to sent an default parameter with all HTTP request. For this I have to add that parameter with every URL

For example :  http://example.com/location/?locale=en - Locale is one of the default parameter.

Snippet :-

```
angular.module('ionic-http-auth.controllers', [])
.controller('LocationCtrl', function($ionicViewService) {
  // List of Locations
  $http.get('http://example.com/location')
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.location = data;
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Error occurred.  Status:" + status);
    });
})

.controller('CustomerCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http) {
  $scope.customers = [];
  // List of Customers
  $http.get('http://example.com/customer')
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.customers = data;
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Error occurred.  Status:" + status);
    });
})
```

Now to add one default parameter, I have to add locale as parameter in all URL. Is their any global function or way to add default parameter with every URL. Because if URL increases then again I have to add default Locale with every URL.

> http://example.com/location/?locale=en
>
> http://example.com/customer/?locale=en

Please suggest something .. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve your goal using $http interceptor(s). These are a factory which is used any time an $http request is made by the application. You can use a request interceptor to modify the url property of the config object.

See
https://djds4rce.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/understanding-angular-http-interceptors/ for more info